# Java - How can I create a JTextfield that can be queried but not updated?

Tags: java

How can I create a `JTextfield` that can be queried but not updated?

Comment: You mean programmatically read-ony? So your clients cannot invoke setText() on it?

Comment: i mean users should be able to enter data in the textfield - so they can invoke getText().This means it can be used as a parameter to a query. but i don't want the value in this textfield being saved into the database.
So user can type into the textfield only in querymode(i am not sure this exists in java).
If it is editmode, users cannot type into the textfield.

Answer (score 7):

```
setEditable(false);
```

Using the above method on a [`JTextField`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) will make it so that a user can't edit the text, but it can still be copied or you can pull the value with `getText()`.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search turned up this example:

[**Create a read-only text field**](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/Createareadonlytextfield.htm)

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class ReadOnlyTextExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));


    // Create a read-only text field
    new Text(shell, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.BORDER).setText("Read Only");


    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do all this when you can `setEditable(false)` as @jjnguy describes?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the UI framework. Try setting

```
xx.setEnabled(false);
```

or

```
xx.setEditable(false);
```

Comment: setting the text field to be disabled usually precludes copying from the field. I think the other answers have this covered better.